# Hamburger icon animation

Tags: html, css, transition

I am working on a hamburger icon animation. The current state of the burger icon is itself the result of what I am trying to achieve. But there is a little odd thing that I am trying to fix.

```
<span  class="burger__icon-lines">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</span>
```

This three-span are three lines of the burger.  Each line has a width of`200%` and the background color of 50% red and 50% black from left. To create animation, Initially, I am showing the black part by giving **negative margin** and **on hover** showing red part.   And for **hover out,** here for each line I am also setting transition delay **to not let** these lines return to its own state so fast because other lines are coming from left which is creating animation as required.

And

```
<span class="burger__icon-lines-copy"> 
    <span></span> 
    <span></span>
    <span></span> 
 </span>
```

These three span are same three line of the burger. *Actually, these are the lines that we see*  in burger icon while **not hovering**.  But while hovering these lines go to left *(hidden)* and comes with animation delay when hovering out.

What I am trying to fix is when I hover if I do it a few times and with not much gap in duration, It looks bad.
 Is there any idea to fix this issue? Thank you.

Here is the fiddle

```css
.burger {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: -16px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.burger .burger__icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.burger__icon-lines, .burger__icon-lines-copy {
  display: block;
}

.burger__icon-lines span,
.burger__icon-lines-copy span {
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 100%;
}

.burger__icon-lines span:first-child,
.burger__icon-lines-copy span:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.burger__icon-lines span {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc3e1d 0%, #fc3e1d 50%, #222 50%, #222 100%);
}

.burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.burger__icon-lines-copy {
  margin-top: -19.5px;
}

.burger__icon-lines-copy span {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: #222;
}

.burger__icon-lines-copy span:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.burger__icon-lines-copy span:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.burger__icon-lines-copy span:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.burger:hover .burger__icon-lines span {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.burger:hover .burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.burger:hover .burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.burger:hover .burger__icon-lines span:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.burger:hover .burger__icon-lines-copy span {
  margin-left: -24px;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="burger">
          <span class="burger__icon">
            <span class="burger__icon-lines">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </span>
            <span class="burger__icon-lines-copy">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </button>
```

Comment: using `spans` for vector graphics slightly like trying to cut with a spoon... I do it all the time, but it's sub-optimal and difficult. Why not [embed / load an SVG and run your animations from there](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)?

Comment: Before going to for SVG, I believe there must be some tweak that I can solve in this way. @Myst

Comment: It improves (but isn't solved) if you avoid updating the `transition-delay` property and avoid the `transition: none` statement. Just set it once per element.